# How to use HttpContext.Current.Session in static property of a abstract class.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ControllerBase abstract class and as below.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    public static string SesssionId
    {
         get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionId"]; }
    }
}
```

I am getting Error

> "object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get"

However I have used the same in other static classes and have not got the above error.

I wonder how the HttpContext is being accessable but not the current.

Could anyone clarify me, what is wrong with the above.

Comment: change to `public string SessionId`

Comment: You could do as @wudzik says. The real problem is, that `Controller` has a property `HttpContext` itself, so the compiler thinks you want to use that. You could state it full-qualified: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your base class `Controller` specifies a [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property itself.
So, when using it in your derived class `ControllerBase`, the compiler thinks you want to refer to this property of the base class.

You could either make the property non-static, as wudzik suggested in the first comment.
I guess this would be the cleaner way to do it.

If you need to keep this property static, you have to tell the compiler, that you want to use the `HttpContext` class of namespace `System.Web`:

```
public static string SesssionId
{
     get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionId"]; }
}
```